# How to open jmeter project in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jmeter

I downloaded and extract jmeter's source code: http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

How do I go about opening this project in IntelliJ?

I tried to 'open project' and navigated to the directory, but it doesn't seem to pickup any of the files to open the project.

Do I have to import or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project over existing source--you can't open a project when there's been no project set up.

IntelliJ will pop up a window with the source directories it discovers; by default they'll all be checked.

You can add the Ant build file in the "Ant Build" tool window to make Ant builds easier.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Since JMeter 5.2 it uses Gradle instead of ant, you can easily import the project into IntelliJ like so:

1. You require IntelliJ 2018.3.1 or newer.
2. Open the `build.gradle.kts` file with IntelliJ IDEA and choose Open as
3. Project Make sure Create separate module per source set is selected
4. Make sure Use default Gradle wrapper is selected
5. In the File already exists dialogue, choose Yes to overwrite
6. In the Open Project dialogue, choose Delete Existing Project and Import (if IntelliJ project already exists)

---

## ORIGINAL

These are the steps I followed to get the [JMeter source code into IntelliJ](https://blog.ham1.co.uk/2015/08/21/setting-up-intellij-idea-14-1-for-jmeter-source/). I've included some screenshots on my blog.

1. Import project from Git: `https://github.com/apache/jmeter.git`
2. Select "Create project from existing sources"
3. Name the project
4. Select all source file directories
5. **De**select any libraries, (add them later)
6. Select all of the discovered modules
7. Select the SDK (you might need to add one if you've not used IntelliJ before)
8. Press Next and then Finish
9. Click the "Ant Build" menu in IntelliJ
10. Press add and add the `build.xml` file
11. Run the `download_jars` target
12. Open project settings (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) then add the downloaded jars to the project

Notes:

- You can compile and start the GUI by executing the `run_gui` ant target
- If there are any errors in IntelliJ when viewing files (or pressing build project) you can usually solve them by pressing alt+enter on the offending code and making the appropriate 'module' a dependency - however this shouldn't stop you developing or running things via ant.

I've also created a screencast of the above steps:
https://youtu.be/r0Z79PjEb80

Comment: If possible can you share detailed steps for gradle project import of jmeter